# Get count of rows + last row inserted

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this sql :

```
SELECT count(*) as nb, data_type, rawValue, createdAt 
FROM my_table WHERE data_type in('t','r', 'b') 
AND  CreatedAt >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 24 HOUR) 
AND CreatedAt <= NOW() AND device=27 AND id=462 
group by data_type order by createdAt DESC ;
```

Now I get data like this :

```
nb       data_type       rawValue           createdAt
20       t               test               2018-08-01 07:30:30
20       r               test               2018-08-01 08:30:30
```

For `data_type = t` I have rows from `2018-08-01 10:10:23` but is getting the first value and not the last by createdAt. Can you help me please ? Thx in advance.

Comment: Tag only DBMS which you are really using.

Comment: use two subqueries returning the two single rows you mention separately, and cross join them together

Comment: @Cato Can you help me please ?

Comment: That doesn't look like SQL Server. `NOW()`, `DATE_SUB` and `interval` are not SQL Server functions or key words (or at least, not in the context used). *Also `FROM table` would fail, as `table` is a reserved word. If your table really is called `table`, in SQL Server the name would need to be quoted: `[table]`.)*

Comment: @George, I added the mysql tag to your question, guessing that's the DBMS you are using. If my guess is wrong, remove that tag and add the correct one. The solution will depend on the database you are using. Are you sure the results in your question are correct (i.e. `ORDER BY` not honored).

Comment: @DanGuzman we use mysql, and yes the results from question are corrects

Comment: "we use mysql, and yes the results from question are corrects" Not possible or case of extreem luck the results are correct .You are misusing MySQL's GROUP BY "feature" which allows to select columns which are not in the GROUP BY.. Causing non matching data in the selected columns which are not in the GROUP BY in this case rawValue and createdAt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems db is mysql, 
when you will use aggregate function then selection column should be in group by clause . we know now() is returned todays present date time as you given interval 24 hour so just notice when selected is that records fall in this duration or not,because your query is almost ok except group by clause columns, i puts those column in group by clauses

As you expect 1 row per data_type so i changes like below

```
    select T.nd,T.data_type,A.rawValue,T.createdAt from
   (
    SELECT count(*) as nb, data_type, 
    max(createdAt) as createdAt
    FROM table WHERE data_type in('t','r', 'b') 
    AND  CreatedAt >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 24 HOUR) 
    AND CreatedAt <= NOW() AND device=27 AND id=462 
    group by data_type 
    ) as T left join table A
   on T.createdAt=A.createdAt
  and T.data_type=A.data_type
    where A.data_type in ('t','r', 'b')
   AND  A.CreatedAt >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 24 HOUR) 
    AND A.CreatedAt <= NOW() AND device=27 AND id=462
```

It would be great if you share your tables sample data and expected output

Comment: I get a lot of data not 1 row per data_type

Comment: @George share your sample data and expected output it will be easy then to guide you

Comment: @George i edited answer i think you need this type something

Comment: `group by data_type  
    order by createdAt DESC` will probably not work the `GROUP BY` is executed before `ORDER BY` meaning you order on a grouped resultset.

Comment: Nor work very vell :( The createdAt is getting well, but not the coresponding rawValue...For example for : createdAt : 2018-08-01 10:58:52, rawValue is 200 but I get 28...Can you take a look @ZaynulAbadinTuhin

Comment: @George it would be great if you share data where you faced problem

Comment: and definitely i will help you

Comment: The idea is that createdAt is getting well (the last value), but the rawValue is not correspond to createdAt, but is getting the first value

Comment: @George check please and let me know